# Connect and return value of WS Rest JAVA Android. Error 404

Tags: java, android, web-services

I want connect to my WSRest in my app, but `HttpURLConnection.getcodeResponse` returns a 404 response.

Code WS:

```
@Path("/pesquisa")

public class Main { 
    @Path("validaLogin")                                             
    @POST
    @Produces("text/plain") 
    public Boolean login(@PathParam("usuario") String usuario, @PathParam("senha") String senha){
        return new Pesquisa().usuarioExiste(usuario, senha);
    }
}
```

Code in Android:

```
String caminhoWS = null;
try {
    //http://urbanapppeter.ddns.net:8080/wsGestaoPedidosApp/pesquisa/validaLogin/
    caminhoWS = contexto.getString(R.string.URL_VALIDA_LOGIN) + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(usuario, "UTF-8") + "&" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(senha, "UTF-8") ;
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}

try {
    URL url = new URL(caminhoWS);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/plain");
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream()); // here error
        String resultado = Utils.convertInputStreamToString(in);
        return false;
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

`urlConnection.getResponseCode()` = 404 is server not found.

Does anyone have any hint of what it might be?

Thanks.